# Is there a way to uninstall Netbeans which I have installed using umake?

Tags: java, 19.04, netbeans, ubuntu-make

I have use `umake ide netbeans` command to install Netbeans a month ago. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate. I searched everywhere to uninstall Netbeans using umake but didn't find anything solid. Is there some **umake** command to uninstall? I don't see any such command in `umake --help` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
umake ide netbeans --remove
```

See umake's help (again, more precisely), and maybe `man umake` ([online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/umake.1.html)) or locally:

> ```
> $ umake --help | grep -i remove
> -r, --remove          Remove specified framework if installed
> ```

Comment: thanks a lot. I did went to one of the official wiki page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make and serveral other website. There is no mentioning of this. I also view "umake man" or "umake --help" section locally but no such thing. I did tried "remove" argument but I didn't know the pattern to put this. I wish they had explained this in --help section or man section locally like how it is mentioned in online website. Anyway. Thanks a lot.